# Serving a downloadable file in django throws server error

Tags: python, django, server

I am new to django. I am trying to serve downloadable files using django FileWrapper. But, I keep getting internal server error messages.

EDIT: My settings.py

```
DEBUG=True
```

link in html:

```
abcd.com/downloadResult/fileName/
```

My urls.py

```
url(r'^downloadResult/(\w{0,50})/$',"myApp.views.showResult",name="Result"),
```

My views.py

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
def showResult(request,fileName):
    file=open("/path/to/file/"+fileName+".txt","r")
    response=HttpResponse(FileWrapper(file),mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition']='attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(fileName+".txt")
    file.close()
    return response
```

Can someone please direct me to some discussions or point out what I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: No-one can help you if you don't post the actual errors you are getting.

Comment: Server error! This is what I get. @DanielRoseman

Comment: No it isn't. If you're developing, you must have DEBUG=True, so you have a nice traceback with lots of useful information.

Comment: Even when DEBUG=True, I get useful error message when there is something wrong in my python codes but with the above script I just get server error. @DanielRoseman

Comment: probably "server error" is the message printed by an ajax error callback. Take a look at the last lines in your python console

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the problem now. It is the line file.close() before returning the output. Even though DEBUG was set to True, I had to check apache log to find this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem with my code. I closed the file before I return anything. After commenting out the second last line in views.py, it works fine. I found the error message in apache log file but did not get any error message in the browser even though DEBUG was set to True.
Now, the problem with this solution is that, there are files that are opened but never closed.